# Playn - Rendering Hollow Objects

Tags: playn

Is there a standard way to render hollow/vectorial objects (i.e. they have no image attached, only a border)?

I want them to be physically simulated as dynamic objects as well.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do this as just a `Surface`? I thought that's what Surfaces are good for.

Answer (score 2):

If your objects are rectangles, you can call Canvas.strokeRect, as described here:
http://code.google.com/p/playn/wiki/GraphicsArchitecture

As for doing physics on objects, that's a separate question, but you can look at the samples to see how to use Box2D to run a physics sim.